# XmlSerializer gives xml declaration after every product in the file

Tags: c#

```
foreach (var backupDeviceLocationData in _repositoryBackupDeviceLocation.GetAll())
{
    System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer writer =
    new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof (BackupDeviceLocationData));
    using (var file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"C:\DBLog\SaveBackupDevice.xml", true))
    {
      writer.Serialize(file, backupDeviceLocationData);
    }
}
```

Gives this for every objects tag in the list

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

How do i get fix XmlSerializer dosen't write the xml declaration after every product in the file?

Comment: Because you are appending to the file.

Comment: Why would the using statement be inside the for loop, if its the same file each time.

Comment: I simplify larger part of code and removed stuff make it simple. And it didn't change the problem with xml-declaration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the Serialize method overload with namespace parameter:

```
var emptyNs = new XmlSerializerNamespaces(new[] { XmlQualifiedName.Empty });
writer.Serialize(file, backupDeviceLocationData, emptyNs);
```